# Multitouch for two draggables Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, jquery-events, joystick

I have two draggables that work as a joystick. So, I have to be able to get one event in each joystick.

I am using a library called touch-punch but it is not multitouch. I have created my own listener but now I can't drag. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use one event for both joysticks. Then use event.changedTouches[0].pageX; and event.changedTouches[1].pageX; to get the first and second touches.

Comment: Yes, but the draggable is stopped, it doesn´t begin to move. Why?

Comment: I'm going to need the code to investigate, can I have a fiddle please?